# sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, sql-server, iis-6

im trying print records from my db (IIS, MSSQL PHP) but i have this error...

Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

```
<?php

$serverName ="name\SQLEXPRESS";
 $usr="sa";
 $pwd="pasw";
 $db="dbname";

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $db);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);



  $sql = "SELECT first_col, s_col, t_col,  FROM names ";
 $res = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
  while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) {
    print(
    $row['first_col'].",".$row['s_col'].",".$row['t_col'].");

 }  


sqlsrv_close( $conn); 
?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your query failed. This causes `sqlsrv_query()` to return false.

Your error in your query is an errant comma:

```
$sql = "SELECT first_col, s_col, t_col,  FROM names ";
                                    ^^^^
                                    HERE
```

Remove it and your query should work.

FYI, you don't check for errors in your code. You should always check to see if something failed, and if so, get the error message. You would have caught this quickly if you did.

Comment: (just to add some notes to this answer) here is simple example http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

Comment: @klapsius How do you know? What have you done to test this? What other troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: I just change my query to $sql = "SELECT *  FROM names "; and work

Comment: in mS SQL Server that comma will cause the query to fail.

Comment: Received this error with an incorrect/typo in my table name. Double check your table name is correct also with this error.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is too localized and of no help for most users coming from Google, who need rather a generic answer, what to do when one gets such error in general.

This error message doesn't have any particular meaning, it's just a symptom telling us that the query execution failed. While we need to get *the actual error message* from SQL server. Hence every query should be executed in PHP  like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT first_col, s_col, t_col,  FROM names";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($stmt === false) {
    trigger_error(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

What is going on here?

- first, we are checking the query result, if case it's equal to `false`, which means the query failed
- if so, we are calling `sqlsrv_errors()` which returns an array with all errors returned by SQL server
- then we are converting this array to string using print_r()
- and finally, throwing a conventional PHP error that could be handled the same way as any other error

In the end, a failed query will throw a PHP error that explains the reason, so one can read the SQL server error message and then fix it right away or Google this message to get the explanation/practical suggestions for their particular error

Answer (score -1):

If you use Stored Procedure with SQL SERVE, you must use EXEC, in your code you used CALL

$check = sqlsrv_query($conn, "{**CALL** Mem_Users_Accede (?,?,?,?)}", $data);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).