# SQLSRV stored procedure call not working

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

after read a bunch of threads, but i still dont know why my query not work :'(. It just return

```
sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

sql connect is fine 'cause i can query select

already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932611/calling-a-stored-procedure-with-sqlsrv) but no solution for this

Here my code

```
$ma_vt = '24110012A2140850';
$query = "{call dbo.Tondaulist(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";

$params = array(array('OL', SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array('01/02/2015', SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array('BPOL01', SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array('', SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array($ma_vt, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
                array('1', SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
                );
$test = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);
if ($test === FALSE){
    echo 'fail';
}
$arr = sqlsrv_fetch_array($test,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

after an hour of trying, i changed my code like this

```
$query = "{call dbo.Tondaulist(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";

$params = array(array('OL,'),
                array('01/02/2015'),
                array('BPOL01'),
                array(''),
                array('24110012A2140850'),
                array('1')
                );

$smtp = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, $params);

if ($smtp === FALSE){
    echo 'fail';die;
}
sqlsrv_execute($smtp);

 while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($smtp)){
    echo 'ello';
    echo '<br />';
    }
    if( sqlsrv_fetch_array( $smtp ) === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

now stored procedure run but return error: The active result for the query contains no fields.

i run SP in SQL studio and it return 1 row.

this is my stored procedure's params

[image]

Anyone know where i was wrong?

Comment: There are already billions of such questions on Stack Overflow, for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23808512/2675154) one.

Comment: @honk: did u read my question clearly?

Comment: I think so. You claim that you _read a bunch of threads_, but you only name one that didn't help you. And you don't tell us why the other answers didn't help you. So: In how far is your question different from the already existing ones? I can't see this from your question. Could you elaborate this, please?

Comment: my Q seems like a repost, just add more params.

Comment: in other Q, they use no params or sqlsrv_execute. I try exec and it return: Param count and argument count don't match

Comment: I think that you should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27815293/edit) your question and add that information somewhere at its beginning. Otherwise readers might think, similar to me, that this question has already been answered elsewhere and move on. It's more likely that you will receive an answer, if you can make it clearer that you have a new question.

Comment: wew, found a useful thread and change my code, it run with a new error =))

Comment: At which line do you get the error? Using `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` twice is a bad idea if first one is in a loop control.

Comment: @alalp: 2nd one is just for show the error if it not run. i didnt see anything wrong '^'

Comment: So, I assume, `echo 'ello';` and the other `echo` is never processed. Print the `$row` right after(with like `print_r`) while loop and change second if condition to `if($row===false)` to see the real error if any just to be sure. Also, add an error condition after `sqlsrv_execute($smtp);` also.